# Using OAuth2 refresh token in React Redux app

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, redux, redux-framework

I have an app that has `OAuth2` implemented. It works fine, but I'm confused with `refresh_tokens` here. My app is using `React` + `Redux` combination.

I know I need to check if my `access_token` expired and then ask for new one using `refresh_token`. Okay... But when should I refresh it? After the `401` happened or in time when some `API` request that needs authorization is ready (just before send)?

I also know how to use `HTTP` interceptors to get all `API` requests before send or detect the `401` responses.
The problem is I'm confused how to solve the problem in `Redux` flow. How to "freeze" a request for the time the token is being refreshed? Or how to repeat the request when I solve the problem on `401` response?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When first authenticating with server successfully, we will have {access_token, expires_in, refresh_token}. We will store access_token and expires_in in [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and refresh_token in local storage.

Whenever getting access_token for fetching data (you should enhance/wrap the fetch with filling access_token), you'll check if the expires_in is due soon (less than 1 minute, or what you feel comfortable), then we use the refresh_token to request new access_token. And of course, we have to update new result to the storage as well.

Pseudo code:

```
function getToken() {
    const expiresIn = storage.getItem(KEY_EXPIRES_IN);
    const accessToken = storage.getItem(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    if (accessToken
        && (!expiresIn || moment.unix(Number(expiresIn)).diff(moment(),   'minute') > 1)) {
        return accessToken;
    }
    return refreshToken();
}
```

Above function will be called every time you make a request to server.

P/S: you may want to make it as promise to use with isomorphic-fetch